# The [address] tag is ambiguous as-is

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, ambiguous-tags

The [address](/questions/tagged/address) tag has no central focus. I work in the address verification industry (postal/street addresses) so I've subscribed to this tag, to contribute where I can. However, I've seen all sorts of topics in this tag:

- Street addresses (actually seldom)
- "Mail address" (whatever that means, but same as a street address)
- Maps
- Memory addresses / pointers
- URLs
- IP address / MAC address
- Email addresses
- Geocoding
- Address book
- Database normalization
- jQuery Address plugin
- Address bar

I think *once* I dived into [an "address" question that was actually about RAM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10924908/global-variable-assign-ram-addres), but other than that... these topics are far too broad for a single tag.

I know there are all sorts of "ambiguous tag" posts on meta, but I'm not sure myself what to do about this. It'd be nice to clean up or specify more precise tag names.

Comment: Personally, i'd think a tag that *could* be so ambiguous, shouldn't exist at all.  When i hear "address", i think "IP address".  Memory addresses come a close second, and in the context of programming, street addresses barely register at all.

Comment: BTW...WTF?  There's a whole postal address verification *industry*?

Comment: @cHao, once you dive into USPS manuals and certifications for more than a single hour, you'll quickly understand why people have made businesses to serve it up. It's um, complicated, to say the least.

Comment: FWIW, this used to be on meta Stack Overflow. Not sure why it was moved to here, it doesn't belong here.

Comment: This site used to *be* MSO.  It became MSE when SO got its own per-site meta just like all the others.  This question didn't get so much "moved", as "left behind".  :P

Comment: @cHao Ah, okay. How do we move it back to Meta SO?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the tag can't stand on its own to describe the post, it probably shouldn't exist.  You've noticed at least two meanings for the word "address", and that could be broken up into a dozen sub-definitions.  The tag doesn't have (and really, can't reasonably have) a single meaning unless we're going to say "you can *only* tag street-address questions with [address](/questions/tagged/address)", which wouldn't do too much good since the people who would reach for such an ambiguous tag are the same ones who don't read tag definitions anyway.

If you see such a tag, consider switching it to a more useful tag:

- For the stuff you were apparently expecting, it should probably be tagged [postal-address](/questions/tagged/postal-address) (or [mail-address](/questions/tagged/mail-address), or [street-address](/questions/tagged/street-address), depending on actual usage) instead.
- For the RAM questions, [memory-address](/questions/tagged/memory-address).
- For the email one, [email-address](/questions/tagged/email-address).
- For networking, [ip-address](/questions/tagged/ip-address) or [mac-address](/questions/tagged/mac-address).

All of these tags already exist and have a few questions tagged with them.

Comment: What should we do with the tag "address" then? Just let it to continue being? I'll go through as often as I can and re-tag questions, but the "address" tag will keep appearing...

Comment: @Matt: Retag wherever you see it.  I'll do so as well, and recommend that others do the same.  For now, since it's muddled up, there's not a whole lot that can be mechanically done about it.  But once it's not on anymore questions at the "end of the day" (about 8pm EST), it'll stop appearing in the tag list and people who don't know better will be less likely to pick it.  (Since the other tags all include "address", though, they *will* show up.)  With ~750 questions over 4 years, it's a pretty low volume tag; i'm confident we can retag faster than noobs can mistag.  :)

Comment: Cool. I was just wondering how that works. Thanks.

Comment: One more thought: the current address tag wiki describes it to be a memory address. Is there a way to make the two the same tag? (I can work on cleaning up the address tag in the meantime)

Comment: Yes, there's a way to alias one tag to another.  Not sure how that works when both tags already exist and have a bunch of assorted questions, but after some cleanup it'd probably be a good idea.  :)

Comment: FYI — Nobody is using [tag:postal-address] but there are a few [tag:mail-address], so it's probably better to suggest that.

Comment: @KevinReid There are many more [tag:street-address]-tagged questions.