# Alias or remove the [address] tag which is now empty

Tags: feature-request, synonym-request

The [address](/questions/tagged/address) tag is finally disambiguated, and all 600+ questions have been moved into more specific address-based tags. [It was wildly obvious that the questions with the "address" tag were far too varied.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155384/the-address-tag-is-ambiguous-as-is)

During the cleanup process, I estimate these were the most common, more-specific variants:

1. [memory-address](/questions/tagged/memory-address)
2. [ip-address](/questions/tagged/ip-address)
3. [url](/questions/tagged/url)

(Please note that, while there are more [ip-address](/questions/tagged/ip-address) and [url](/questions/tagged/url) questions than [memory-address](/questions/tagged/memory-address) questions, the largest subset of questions that were within [address](/questions/tagged/address) belonged in [memory-address](/questions/tagged/memory-address). Many of them had separate [memory](/questions/tagged/memory) and [address](/questions/tagged/address) tags, which were combined.)

**[I recommend we alias [address] to [memory-address]](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/address/synonyms)**, since that seemed to be the most common meaning when people typed the word "address" as a tag. However, I am not opposed to aliasing it to either [ip-address](/questions/tagged/ip-address) or [url](/questions/tagged/url), or another specific tag, if that is preferred. (Unfortunately I am not able to suggest either of those synonyms on the main site.)

Comment: Since there are zero questions now, it will simply go away on its own (within 24 hours).  I say let it die and then make a decision on a synonym if it comes back.

Comment: Actually, looks like it was already cleaned up last night

Comment: Excellent. I didn't know that. Thank you.